# Bi-invariant metrics on compact Polish group

Tags: topological-groups

Let $(X,\tau,\circ)$ be a compact Polish group. Is there necessarily a metric $d$ on $X$ inducing $\tau$ such that $d(x \circ a,x \circ b) = d(a \circ x, b \circ x) = d(a,b)$ for all $x,a,b \in X$?

If the answer is yes, I would appreciate a sketch of the argument establishing this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes - the existence of a left-invariant metric on any Hausdorff first countable group is the Birkhoff-Kakutani theorem. Given a left-invariant metric $d$ on a compact group then just put 
$$
d'(a,b)=\sup_x d(ax,bx) \;.
$$

PS Of course, the point is that all these metrics metrize the group topology.

Comment: @NateEldredge the argument shows how to pass from left-invariant to bi-invariant.

Comment: @YCor: Ah, of course.  I need to read more carefully.

Comment: The argument can be adapted to move directly from an arbitrary metric to the bi-invariant one, and thus serves my needs (upvote!). Invoking Birkhoff-Kakutani seems overkill though.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternative argument based on the Peter-Weyl theorem.

1) if $G$ is a connected compact Lie group, it has a bi-invariant Riemannian metric, which induces a bi-invariant distance.

2) if $G$ is a compact Lie group, choose a distance as in (1) on $G^0$, normalized so that the diameter is $\le 1$; extend it by left translation on each component, and say that any two points in different components have distance 1. This is a bi-invariant distance inducing the topology.

3) if $G$ is a product $\prod_nG_n$ of a sequence $(G_n)$ of compact Lie groups, choose a bi-invariant distance $d_n$ on $G_n$ of diameter $\le 1$ inducing the topology of $G_n$: then $d(g,h)=\sum_n2^{-n}d(g_n,h_n)$ is a bi-invariant distance inducing the topology of $G$.

4) if $G$ is an arbitrary compact metrizable topological group, it embeds, by the Peter-Weyl theorem, as a closed subgroup of $\prod_nG_n$ for some sequence $(G_n)$ of compact Lie groups. Using (3) and restricting, we get a bi-invariant distance on $G$ inducing the topology.

Comment: Side remark: it's used implicitly that on a compact Hausdorff topological space $X$, a distance induces the topology iff it's continuous. Indeed $\Rightarrow$ is clear, and conversely, $d$ continuous implies that the identity map $X\to (X,d)$ is continuous bijective; since $X$ is compact Hausdorff this implies that it is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is quite trivially yes. We have available to us some metric $d'$ inducing the topology $\tau$. We then define
$$d(a,b) = \sup_{x \in \mathbf{X}} \quad \sup_{y \in \mathbf{X}} \quad d'(x \circ a \circ y, x \circ b \circ y)$$

Now $d$ inherits the property of being a metric from $d'$, and the bi-invariance is immediate from the construction.

As $\mathbf{X}$ is compact, $d$ is continuous w.r.t. $\tau$. As pointed out by YCor in the comments, whenever $(X,\tau)$ is compact Hausdorff and $d$ is a continuous metric on $(X,\tau)$, then $d$ already induces $\tau$ (as continuous bijections from compact spaces into Hausdorff spaces have continuous inverses).

The idea is taken from the answer by R W, but the use of Birkhoff-Kakutani is overkill here.

Comment: This is indeed the simplest argument and I'd be happy to upvote it. However RW first posted a complete answer to your question, and given the usual use of this site, it would be fair to accept his/her answer.